# Start and Stop threads with while loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm building a tkinter GUI to retrieve incoming data from a device (through request) and appending them into a csv file, while having a preview of these data.

I use `thread` but struggle to understand it properly, especially how to pause and restart it.

When I click on the start button, my threads are working properly. Once I try to click the stop streaming button, my `stop_threads` variable change to 0, however, the while loop in my thread do not see this change. Do you know why?

Thanks a lot!

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from tkinter import ttk


def init_csv():
    pass
    # create my csv file here

def clear_data():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    init_csv()


def stream_data():
    global stop_threads
    IP_Machine = IP_entry.get()

    while True:
        if stop_threads == 1:
            print('Stream')
            # retrieve incoming data from my device (through request)
            # appending them into a csv file

        if stop_threads == 0:
            print('Pause')
            # I want to pause this thread here


def start_stream():
    t1_stream.start()
    stream_label['text'] = 'Streaming...'
    button_start.destroy()

    # Create stop streaming button
    button_stop = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Stop Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12',
                            command=stop_stream)
    button_stop.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)


def stop_stream():
    stop_threads = 0
    stream_label['text'] = ''

    # Create ReStart streaming button
    button_restart = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Start Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12',
                               command=restart)
    button_restart.place(relx=0, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)


def restart():
    stop_threads = 1
    stream_label['text'] = 'Streaming...'


def curve():
    # show live plot data with matplot Funcanimation
    pass


def refresch_treeview():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    # define content of the treeview and refrech
    tv1.after(500, refresch_treeview)


csv_path = 'C:/Users/b/Desktop/testfile.csv'
init_csv()
global stop_threads
stop_threads = 1

# Multitasking definition
t1_stream = threading.Thread(target=stream_data)
t2_refresch = threading.Thread(target=refresch_treeview)

# My Tkinter interface bellow
root = tk.Tk()

# Variables
Bg_color = '#F2F2F2'
Blue = '#045FB4'
c_width = 1400
c_height = 700

# Template
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=c_height, width=c_width, bg=Bg_color)
canvas.pack()
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
left_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.05, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.002, relheight=0.9)
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
right_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.95, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.002, relheight=0.9)
top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
top_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.004)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
bottom_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.95, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.004)
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Bg_color)
main_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)
# Title
title = tk.Label(root, text='Data analysis', height=2, width=20, font='bold 18')
title.place(anchor='center', relx=0.50, rely=0.05)

# ENTRIES Definition
# Machine IP
IP_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=Bg_color)
IP_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.05)
IP_label = tk.Label(IP_frame, text='2000Xc IP address : ', font='12')
IP_label.pack(side='left', fill='y')
IP_entry = tk.Entry(IP_frame, width=22, font='12')
IP_entry.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# Streaming runing label
stream_label = tk.Label(main_frame, font='10', text='')
stream_label.place(anchor='w', relx=0, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.06)

# BUTTONS Definition
# Start streaming button
button_start = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Start Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12', command=start_stream)
button_start.place(relx=0, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)

# Clear data
button_clear = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Clear data", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 10', command=clear_data)
button_clear.place(relx=0.92, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.06)
# Show graph button
button_graph = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Show curves", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 10', command=curve)
button_graph.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.05)

# csv preview
preview_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=Bg_color)
preview_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.5, relwidth=1, relheight=0.4)
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(preview_frame)
tv1.place(relheight=0.95, relwidth=1)  # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).
# scroll preview
treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(preview_frame, orient="vertical",
                           command=tv1.yview)  # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(preview_frame, orient="horizontal",
                           command=tv1.xview)  # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set,
              yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)  # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")  # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")  # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget

t2_refresch.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey Baptiste, you will get better answers when you supply us a minimum working example. I can´t reproduce this directly since there are missing imports and variables

Comment: Hey, I add the detail to the code which know could be run as is. My problem is, if you clic on the start button, it will print 'Stream', which is good. However after this, when the 'stop stream' button is pressed, it continue to print 'Stream' instead of 'Pause'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change only one thing. You need to define stop_threads as global inside the functions. Python then knows that you are referring to the global variable instead of creating a new variable inside the local function scope.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from tkinter import ttk


def init_csv():
    pass
    # create my csv file here

def clear_data():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    init_csv()


def stream_data():
    global stop_threads
    IP_Machine = IP_entry.get()

    while True:
        if stop_threads == 1:
            print('Stream')
            # retrieve incoming data from my device (through request)
            # appending them into a csv file

        if stop_threads == 0:
            print('Pause')
            # I want to pause this thread here


def start_stream():
    t1_stream.start()
    stream_label['text'] = 'Streaming...'
    button_start.destroy()

    # Create stop streaming button
    button_stop = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Stop Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12',
                            command=stop_stream)
    button_stop.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)


def stop_stream():
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads = 0
    stream_label['text'] = ''

    # Create ReStart streaming button
    button_restart = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Start Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12',
                               command=restart)
    button_restart.place(relx=0, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)


def restart():
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads = 1
    stream_label['text'] = 'Streaming...'


def curve():
    # show live plot data with matplot Funcanimation
    pass


def refresch_treeview():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    # define content of the treeview and refrech
    tv1.after(500, refresch_treeview)


csv_path = 'C:/Users/b/Desktop/testfile.csv'
init_csv()

stop_threads = 1

# Multitasking definition
t1_stream = threading.Thread(target=stream_data)
t2_refresch = threading.Thread(target=refresch_treeview)

# My Tkinter interface bellow
root = tk.Tk()

# Variables
Bg_color = '#F2F2F2'
Blue = '#045FB4'
c_width = 1400
c_height = 700

# Template
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=c_height, width=c_width, bg=Bg_color)
canvas.pack()
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
left_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.05, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.002, relheight=0.9)
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
right_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.95, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.002, relheight=0.9)
top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
top_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.004)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Blue)
bottom_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.95, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.004)
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=Bg_color)
main_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)
# Title
title = tk.Label(root, text='Data analysis', height=2, width=20, font='bold 18')
title.place(anchor='center', relx=0.50, rely=0.05)

# ENTRIES Definition
# Machine IP
IP_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=Bg_color)
IP_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.05)
IP_label = tk.Label(IP_frame, text='2000Xc IP address : ', font='12')
IP_label.pack(side='left', fill='y')
IP_entry = tk.Entry(IP_frame, width=22, font='12')
IP_entry.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# Streaming runing label
stream_label = tk.Label(main_frame, font='10', text='')
stream_label.place(anchor='w', relx=0, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.06)

# BUTTONS Definition
# Start streaming button
button_start = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Start Streaming", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 12', command=start_stream)
button_start.place(relx=0, rely=0.14, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.07)

# Clear data
button_clear = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Clear data", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 10', command=clear_data)
button_clear.place(relx=0.92, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.06)
# Show graph button
button_graph = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Show curves", bg=Blue, fg=Bg_color, font='BOLD 10', command=curve)
button_graph.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.05)

# csv preview
preview_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=Bg_color)
preview_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.5, relwidth=1, relheight=0.4)
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(preview_frame)
tv1.place(relheight=0.95, relwidth=1)  # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).
# scroll preview
treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(preview_frame, orient="vertical",
                           command=tv1.yview)  # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(preview_frame, orient="horizontal",
                           command=tv1.xview)  # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set,
              yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)  # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")  # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")  # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget

t2_refresch.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot, I was struggling with this for 2 days and it was only that little thing.. I feel sorry that I bothered you guys for such a small issue, but it help me to learn more each time!.Thank you very much for the support, it's working properly now!

Comment: You´re welcme. That´s what stackoverflow is for :)